# Add System Security to Migration Flag Options

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration

This may be a dup but I haven't seen it. With a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001640/how-was-snapchats-api-reverse-engineered#comment31561417_21001640), security is just a better fit. I am not entirely sure how adding options to this works but I think it would be helpful.

Comment: That question seems too broad to be migrated elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see a question that you think is off-topic on Stack Overflow but on-topic on some other site:

1. Flag or vote to close it as off-topic.
2. Flag it as “other” and explain why you think it should be migrated to that other site.

Example:

> Please migrate to [reindeer.se]. I'm a regular there and this is a run-of-the-mill question for us.

---

As a general matter, there aren't that many questions on Stack Overflow that should be migrated to Security. Furthermore I would expect a lot of false positives: questions about the security of a piece of code are on-topic on Stack Overflow; questions about removing viruses or using software that happens to implement some security function are off-topic on Security.

---

Speaking as a [security.se] regular, this particular question should not be migrated nor reposted as is. There are two distinct questions here. “What can we do to protect our own REST API's” is far too broad. “How was SnapChat's API reverse engineered?” may or may not be on-topic: reverse-engineering an API is not a matter of security; however the it may be that the SnapChat breach in fact involved extracting some keys (I'm not familiar with this particular incident). In the latter case, the question may be on-topic, but we would expect the question to demonstrate what the security concern is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation both here and on the original question that makes sense